# Getting all the input arguments excepting the first one

Tags: shell

```
for arg; do
    if [ $cnt -gt 1 ]; then
        TXT+=" "
        TXT+=$arg
    fi
    cnt=$(( $cnt + 1 ))
done
```

I just want to get $2 $3 $4 ... $n (without $1)
What I have done works but it seems to be overkill.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use:

```
shift
```

to remove first argument passed to your script.

As per `help shift`:

```
help shift
shift: shift [n]
    Shift positional parameters.

    Rename the positional parameters $N+1,$N+2 ... to $1,$2 ...  If N is
    not given, it is assumed to be 1.

    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless N is negative or greater than $#.
```